# Pyspark Rename column based on column position

Tags: pyspark

How do I rename the 3rd column of a dataframe in PySpark. I want to call the column index rather than the actual name.

Here is my attempt:

```
df
Col1    Col2    jfdklajfklfj
   A       B               2

df.withColumnRenamed([3], 'Row_Count')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since python indexing starts at 0, you can index `df.columns` list by subtracting 1:

```
index_of_col = 3
df.withColumnRenamed(df.columns[index_of_col-1],'Row_Count').show()
```

---

```
+----+----+---------+
|Col1|Col2|Row_Count|
+----+----+---------+
|   A|   B|        2|
+----+----+---------+
```